# Issues with Imebra Dicom SDK

Tags: android, dicom, imebra

I'm trying to read a dicom file using the instructions given in "Adding Imebra to your Intellij Idea" and I am facing issues.

The exact code snippet where am facing the issue is this:

```
Stream stream = new Stream();
stream.openFileRead("/sdcard/Download/87FDH4G2.dcm");
```

The error I get is that the stream cannot be opened. I have placed the file. But still I am getting this error. Please suggest me.

Comment: can you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This allows you to write to the external storage, and reading permission is included (I've tried only the read permission, but it didn't work for me, but write which has read included did... weird, but it worked).